# confirming installed RAM is 100% compatible

Tags: windows, ubuntu, memory

Say I went to upgrade my Laptop's RAM into a PC store, I'm still doubtful that whether the store upgraded my RAM correctly and that I will have no problem in the future. If I'd like to make sure 100% that they installed the RAM correctly with all specs matching, is there any software/method that I can use to confirm that the newly installed RAM was 100% compatible with my existing one and that I will have no problem in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always do the following:

1. Find your exact laptop online. So look up the exact model and everything. Did you order it from an ecommerce website? Go to your order, copy your brand name and model.
2. While looking up that model, go find the memory/RAM section.
3. How much RAM can go in there maximum? That means how many sticks (i.e. 4 maximum?), how much GB in total maximum (i.e. 32 or 64 or ... ?), and how much MHz (i.e. 2666 exactly).

   My laptop is the following: *Asus ROG Strix GL531GU-AL061T*, so it can go up to: 32GB and with 2,666 GHz/2666 MHz. I have 16gb RAM installed. I need to know if I have 2 slots occupied or 1 so I can look for another 16GB RAM stick or maybe do something different (like completely remove that 16GB and get myself 2 16's or 1 32).
4. If you have brand x installed already, just go for that exact brand if possible, but it shouldn't matter if your GHz/total GB are the same.
5. Faulty sticks could always come inside the package, so if something is going on, and you know the stick you or someone else installed is 100% compatible, you can still call the organization of the RAM.

tl:dr

- Look up exact model.
- Look up the GHz / maximum GB RAM / brand name.
- Get yourself the same specs.
- Faulty sticks exist so that could be the reason something goes downhill even if you did everything perfectly while looking up and installing the RAM.

Comment: I was looking for a software based solution that would let me compare the specs/information about the two sticks...

Comment: You can install CPU-Z, and compare both sticks one at the time to see if they match (read "are the same"). Do this in the "Memory" tab inside the mentioned application. There you can read all the specs. Good luck.